# Gtk. Can't get HdyClamp object through GtkBuilder in C

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gtk3

I have the following `HdyClamp` declaration in a `.ui` file. `HdyClamp` is defined in the `libhandy` api. [see here](https://honk.sigxcpu.org/projects/libhandy/doc/)

```
 .......

 <object class="HdyClamp" id="cl">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">False</property>
            <child>
 .......
```

Since `HdyClamp` is also a `GtkWidget`, I thought I should be able to get this object through `GtkBuilder` and store it in a `GtkWidget` object. Here is the code.

```
 GtkWidget * clamp = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "cl"));
```

Where `builder` is a `GtkBuilder` object associated with the `.ui` file. The result is that `clamp` is `NULL` after that line which means `gtk_builder_get_object()` failed to return the `HdyClamp` object with the given ID `cl`. I am really not sure why this happens and would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you called `hdy_init()` in your application startup code? Also, there should be an error message from GTK on the console; it would help if you include that.

Comment: I tried to call `hdy_init()` but the compiler doesn't seem to recognize the function call and doesn't compile. I have included `<handy.h>` appropriately and I can call several functions from the library just fine but `hdy_init()` or `hdy_clamp_new()` for example don't work. I am not sure why.

Comment: What version of libhandy are you using? Some older versions don't have hdy_init or HdyClamp.

Comment: I have cloned the latest version of it as a subproject to my project.

Comment: Ah, I recloned the repository and It turned out I actually did not clone the version I needed. I has fixed now. Thanks you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed, see the comments under the post.